# POST em WebAPI Azure gerando Timeout

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma WebAPI hospedada no Azure, porém, quando há muitas requisições POST, o azure retorna timeout (só funciona as duas primeiras, em média). Alguém já passou por esse problema antes?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jean, vc pode mandar o codigo do WebAPI, pois esse que vc postou é do client consumindo o API, certo? Certamente irá nos ajudar a te ajudar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jean, muito estranho este comportamento. Você está hospedando sua WEBAPI em um website?

Se sim, valide se o mesmo encontra-se no modo gratuito (pode ser um problema). No entanto, mesmo no modo gratuito, você deveria conseguir mais respostas.

O que eu imagino que esteja acontecendo. Sua WEBAPI fica um tempo sem receber requisições e o IIS coloca seu site (api) em standby. No Request seguinte, o IIS sobe o site novamente, mas por algum motivo, o cliente da sua API deve estar com um timeout baixo.

Configure o modo always on e veja se resolve seu problema: